# Vercel: Rewriting the root page

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have two rewrites in vercel.json and only one of them works:

```
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/vault/:path*",
            "destination": "http://vault-snail.vercel.app/:path*"
        },
        {
            "source": "/",
            "destination": "https://vault-extracter.wordpress.com"
        },
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true
}
```

I want to rewrite everything from maildomain.com/vault to `http://vault-snail.vercel.app` (that is the case that works). But also, I want the root page to be rewritten by `https://vault-extracter.wordpress.com` page. This is the case that doesn't work. No matter what I try, It seems I cannot rewrite the root of the page.

Is there any way or idea how this can be solved?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/27